# How to complete this function then print it out, using Python?

Tags: python, reverse

I'm having a hard time to understand how to work with functions - I can make then but after that I don't know how to use them. My question is how can I print this code with a function?

```
string = "Hello"
reverse = string[::-1]
print(reverse)
```

I tried putting it in a function but I cannot make it print Hello.

```
def reverse_a_string(string):
    string = "Hello"
    reverse = string[::-1]
    print(reverse)
```

also tried this

```
def reverse_a_string(string):
    string = "Hello"
    reverse = string[::-1]

print(reverse)
```

Nothing seems to work. I'm having same problem with this as well.

```
total = 0

def length(words):

    for i in words:
        total += 1
    return total
```

Comment: You must be following a _very bad_ tutorial, man... If you pass some value to a function, it doesn't normally _replace_ its contents with a constant right away. You call functions simply like `sin(radians(30))` or, in your case, similar to `print(length(["hello", "world"]))`

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Your first example works just fine.

Comment: @pvg, as far as I understand, he doesn't know how to _call functions_...

Comment: In your second code add this `reverse_a_string('hello')` outside the function.Just search how to call a function you will get it.

Comment: @ForceBru oh that makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Functions without a return value

Functions that just take action or do something without returning a value (for example, `print`).
Functions that don't return a value can be defined like that:

```
def sayHello():
    print "Hello!"
```

And can be used (called) like that:

```
sayHello()
```

And the output will be:

> Hello!

## Function parameters

A function can also receive parameters (type of variables) from the caller. It's better to demonstrate it with an example.
A function that receives a name and greets this name:

```
def sayHelloTo(name):
    print "Hello", name
```

It can be called like that:

```
sayHelloTo("Yotam")
```

And the output will be:

> Hello Yotam

The parameters are the function's input.

## Functions with a return value

Other functions, unlike `sayHello()` or `sayHelloTo(name)` (that just do something) can return a value. For example, let's make a function that rolls a dice (returns a random number between 1 and 6).
from random import randint

```
def rollDice():
    result = randint(1, 6)
    return result
```

The `return` keyword just sets the `output value` of the function and exits the function. An example use of the `rollDice` function will be:

```
dice = rollDice()
print "The dice says", dice
```

When the function hits a `return` keyword, it finishes and the return value (in our case, the variable `result`) will be placed instead of the function call. Let's assume `randint(1, 6)` has produced the number 3.
Result becomes 3.
Result is returned.
Now, instead of the line:

```
dice = rollDice()
```

We can treat the line as:

```
dice = 3
```

(`rollDice()` was replaced with `3`)

## Functions with parameters and a return value

Some functions (for example, math functions) can take inputs AND produce outputs. For example, let's make a function that receives 2 numbers and outputs the greater one.

```
def max(a,b):
    if a > b:
        return a
    else:
        return b
```

What it does is pretty clear, isn't it? If `a` is greater, it returns the value of it. Otherwise, returns the value of `b`.
It can be used like that:

```
print max(4, 6)
```

And the output will be:

> 6

## Now, your case

What you want to do is a function that reverses a string. It should take 1 parameter (input) - the string you want to reverse, and output 1 value - the reversed string. This can be accomplished like that:

```
def reverse_a_string(my_text):
    return my_text[::-1]
```

now you can do something like that:

```
s = raw_input("Please enter a string to be reversed\n") #input in Python3
r = reverse_a_string(s)
print r
```

r will contain the reversed value of s, and will be printed.
About your second function - well, I assume that based on this answer you can make it yourself, but comment me if you need assistance with the second one.

## Local variables

About your 3rd example:

```
def reverse_a_string(string):
    string = "Hello"
    reverse = string[::-1]

print(reverse)
```

This is something that is really worth delaying and understanding.
the variable `reverse` is first used **inside the function**. This makes it a **local variable**.
This means that the variable is stored in the memory when the function is called, and when it finishes, it is removed. You can say it's lifetime is from when the function is called to when the function is done.
This means that even if you called `reverse_a_string(string)`, you wouln't be able to use the `reverse` variable outside of the function, because it would be **local**.
If you do want to pass a value like that, you have to "declare" your variable outside of the function and to use the **global** keyword, like that:

```
reverse = "" #This makes reverse a global variable
def reverse_a_string(string):
    global reverse #Stating that we are going to use the global variable reverse
    reverse = string[::-1]

# Then you can call it like that:
reverse_a_string("Hello")
print reverse
```

The output will be

> olleH

Although it's **strongly not recommended** to do it in Python, or in any other language.

Answer (score 2):

Once you create a function you must call it. You have created the function `reverse_a_string` but then you never actually call it. Think about a function as a button that does something everytime it is pushed (or in our case called). If you never push the button then although it has the potential to do something, it *never* will. In order for the set of instructions to happen we need to push the button (or in our case call the function). So in order for your code to work you first need to define the function then actually call it:

```
def reverse_a_string():
    string="Hello"
    reverse = string[::-1]
    print reverse
```

reverse_a_string()

Result: 'olleH'

If you want to pass your own string in to the function so it doesn't just return 'olleH' all the time your code needs to look like such:

```
def reverse_a_string(stringThatWillBeReversed):
    reverse = stringThatWillBeReversed[::-1]
    print reverse

reverse_a_string('whateverStringYouWant')
```

Result: The reverse of the string you entered.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you are asking how to define functions in python or something else

If you want to learn python functions, go to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm or just write python tutorial in google, you will get billions of good sites

```
def reverse_a_string(string): 
     #function definition
     reverse = string[::-1] 
     print(reverse)

#function call
reverse_a_string("your string")
```

But you to define function for this, you could simply do

```
   print( string[::-1] )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# defines the 'Reverse a String' function and its arguments
def reverse_a_string():
    print(string)
    reverse = string[::-1]
    print(reverse)


print("Type a string") # asks the user for a string input
string = input() # assigns whatever the user input to the string variable
reverse_a_string() # simply calls the function
```

for functions, you have to define the function, then simply call it with the function name  i.e. funtion()

In my example, I ask for a string, assign that to the variable, and use it within the function.  If you just want to print hello (I'm a little unclear from your question) then simply including the print("hello") or w/ variable print(string) will work inside the function as well.